# Since strict-mode is enabled, changing (observed) observable values without using an action is not allowed. Tried to modify: OrderLine@1.price

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx

```
class OrderLine {
    price = 0
    amount = 1
    stop = () => { }

    constructor(price: number) {
        makeObservable(this, {
            price: observable,
            amount: observable,
            total: computed
        })

        this.stop = autorun(() => {
            console.log("Total: " + this.total)
        })

        this.price = price
    }

    get total() {
        console.log("Computing...")
        return this.price * this.amount
    }
}

export default new OrderLine(0)
```

i get warning

> Since strict-mode is enabled, changing (observed) observable values without using an action is not allowed. Tried to modify: OrderLine@1.price

what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

mobx documentation  ******

```
class OrderLine {
    price = 0
    amount = 1
    stop = () => { }

    constructor(price: number) {
        this.price = price

        makeObservable(this, {
            price: observable,
            amount: observable,
            total: computed
        })
        this.stop = autorun(() => {
            console.log("Total: " + this.total)
        })

    }

    get total() {
        console.log("Computing...")
        return this.price * this.amount
    }
}

export default new OrderLine(0)
```

`this.price = price` before  `makeObservable`